# Re-creating complex CSS footer layout in Drupal

Tags: theming

I've been given some HTML & CSS files by our university web designer and need to replicate essentially the same layout into the library website I'm creating in Drupal. The footer (pleased see attached link) has been the biggest hurdle so far. With this type of column-based inline layout consisting of menus (which I haven't created as menus yet), should I be creating new regions in my .info file to handle each menu? Also with the university address info. and icons, should this be another region or should I add custom variables and HTML so it is just part of the main footer region? Or is there a way using Blocks, Panels or another module to create this layout more efficiently?

One last thing-as you can see the columns have three headings (Who Are You?, Quicklinks, and Admissions) so I plan to create a menu with each name as title. What's the best strategy to deal with the overflow of menu items over more than one column without having to create six separate inline regions for layout purposes?

Thanks for any assistance, guidance, or suggestions. This site has been an invaluable resource in learning Drupal over the past few months and I've learned a lot from all your posts, responses & comments to each other.

**The footer design:**
[footer http://dl.dropbox.com/u/664958/footer.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/664958/footer.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd set up one region for those menus, in that region have 3 x menu blocks (http://drupal.org/project/menu_block), 1) Who Are You, 2) Quicklinks 3) Admissions.

CSS will be your friend to get the required layouts.

The "Who Are You" menu should be easy, float the menu block left and fix the width. The same for the "Admissions" menu.

The middle menu will be similar but all you need to do is have a wider fixed width menu block, fix the width of the menu items and float them left. Then you'll have to order the menu items to make them appear in the correct columns.

The text below the menus should simply be 2-3 more standard text blocks just styled appropriately.

I hope this makes sense. I'll be interested to see how other developers would attack this.

Cheers.

Comment: I was just going to suggest that module. Having 1 big list of links it's easy to drag&drop and edit. Then split them by by depth with menu_block.

Answer (score 0):

The Skinr module can help with this kind of thing: http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/support/documentation/layout/adding-menu-your-sites-footer

If you are using Drupal 6, I would try it out. It is not quite ready for 7, but it is probably worth looking at anyway. There are a lot of other things that it can make easier, and many base themes have some built in support for it.

Comment: I've thought about using Skinr because, while someone else created the CSS, trying to map or cross-walk the style info (divs, spans, classes, IDs, et. al) from one of the HTML files to a template like Fusion or Zen is another daunting task I have to face.

Comment: If you are thinking of using Fusion, you really should try Skinr out, the built in Skinr styles will get you part of the way there.